# Limit jQuery Mobile slider to responding to press-hold-drag

Tags: jquery-mobile, scroll, slider

On iPad Safari (and desktop Safari and Chrome), I need to have horizontal sliders on a page that scrolls vertically, where the sliders can't accidentally be moved.  Unfortunately, jQuery mobile sliders do respond to (imperfect) vertical swipes on iPad.

A nice way to fix this is to set up the sliders so that the only way to move the knob is to press-hold and then drag.  Here's what I've hacked together (note: this only works on touch interfaces):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<style>
div.input-container {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="top">
    <div>
        <h1>Sliders for iPad</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="test1">Test:</label>
        <div class="input-container">
            <input type="range" name="test1" value="50" min="0" max="100" disabled>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <div>
        <label for="test2">Test:</label>
        <div class="input-container">
            <input type="range" name="test2" value="50" min="0" max="100" disabled>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <div>
        <label for="test3">Test:</label>
        <div class="input-container">
            <input type="range" name="test3" value="50" min="0" max="100" disabled>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {

$(".input-container").addClass("disable-drag")
    .on("taphold", tapholdHandler)
    .on('touchmove', moveHandler)
    .on('touchend', endHandler)
;

function moveHandler(event) {
    var containingDiv = $(".input-container");
    if (!containingDiv.hasClass('disable-drag')) {
        ///
        console.log(event);
        $('a').offset({left: event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].clientX});
        var left = 68;///parseInt($('.ui-slider-track')[0].css('margin-left'));
        var w = event.originalEvent.target.offsetWidth - left;
        var percent = ((event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].clientX - left) / w) * 100;
        $('input').val(percent).slider('refresh');
        ///
    }
}

function tapholdHandler(event) {
    console.log(event)
    var containingDiv = $(".input-container");
    if (containingDiv.hasClass('disable-drag')) {
        containingDiv.removeClass("disable-drag");
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('input').slider('enable').slider('refresh');
    }
}

function endHandler(event) {
    $('input').slider('disable').slider('refresh');
    $(".input-container").addClass("disable-drag")
}

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The slider is disabled until a press-hold is detected, at which time it springs to life, updates the knob position and value while the user drags, and returns to disabled when touch ends.  It kind of works, but is too brittle and I don't want to be doing essentially the same calcs that the slider already does.  Between the /// markers what I'd really like is to programmatically click at the current mouse location so that the knob moves to that spot - without interrupting the press-hold-drag gesture.  Is this possible?  Here's what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
///
$(".ui-slider-track").trigger('click'); //todo: narrow the selector to the target slider
///
```

and

```
///
$(document.elementFromPoint(event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].clientX, event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].clientY)).click();
///
```

...or is there some other mobile UI library with sliders that don't respond to vertical swipes?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out a fairly clean simple solution.  Tested on iPad Safari.  It also keeps the text field enabled so it can be edited directly.

```
<script>
    // The following manages the sliders so that vertical swiping (scrolling) never inadvertently changes a slider value
    $(function() {
        var timerId;
        $.event.special.tap.tapholdThreshold = 250;  // default is 750, but that seems too long for this scenario

        $(".input-container")
            .on('taphold', tapholdHandler)
            .on('touchmove', moveHandler)
            .on('touchend', endHandler)
        ;
        $('.input-container input')
            .prop('disabled', false).removeClass('ui-state-disabled')  // allow the user to edit the displayed value
            .on('change', function() {
                $(this).slider('refresh');
                $(this).prop('disabled', false).removeClass('ui-state-disabled');  // override the above line's disabling of the text field
                $(this).blur();
            })
        ;

        function tapholdHandler(event) {
            $(event.currentTarget).find('input').slider('enable').slider('refresh');
        }

        function moveHandler(event) {
            if (timerId)
                clearTimeout(timerId);  // as long as the user is interacting with the slider, don't revert it to disabled
            $(document.elementFromPoint(event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].clientX, event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].clientY)).trigger('vmousedown');
        }

        function endHandler(event) {
            $(document.elementFromPoint(event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientX, event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientY)).trigger('vmousedown').trigger('vmouseup');  // the purpose of this is to move the slider knob even if the user's touch didn't move
            timerId = setTimeout(function() {  // give the above induced event time to run the associated handler
                    $(event.currentTarget).find('input').slider('disable').slider('refresh');
                    $(event.currentTarget).find('input').prop('disabled', false).removeClass('ui-state-disabled');  // allow the user to edit the displayed value
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
</script>
```